# How do I add a prefix/suffix to each line of a file?

Tags: bash

For example, file1 contains:

```
entry1:value1
entry2:value2
entry3:value3
```

Now I want to add a prefix "file1:" to each line:

```
file1:entry1:value1
file1:entry2:value2
file1:entry3:value3
```

How can I do that in one command line?

I'm using Bash.

BTW, the leading space must be preserved, so the Bash built-in read line doesn't work for me.

Comment: At last, I decided to write a small C program. All command-line utilities seem have a limitation when PREFIX/SUFFIX contains special chars.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
% sed 's/^/file1:/' file1
```

Comment: The only problem of sed is, how to escape my prefix if it contains special chars?

Comment: that is not a problem of 'sed' but of your quoting skills :)

Comment: Well, the prefix/suffix is variable indeed, it's not easy to quote all special chars, and even I can quote them all, the script maybe not portable at all.

Answer (score 2):

Using AWK, you can add pretty much any prefix:

```
awk -v PRE='anything:' '{$0=PRE$0; print}' file1
```

This will work even for fancy non-printable chars.

Answer (score 2):

The most readable and easy to remember one for me to add both **prefix and suffix** is the following:

```
$ echo "  foo bar  " | awk '{print "--"$0"++"}'
```

which outputs

```
  --  foo bar  ++
```

Note the whole input including leading/trailing spaces is preserved.

Comment: Thank you! This really is the easiest way compared to all the other answers and does and both prefix and suffix as an example. Perhaps replace `echo` with `cat filename`

Comment: Thank you. I thought this was very easy to do as someone pretty new to Bash

Answer (score 1):

`read` splits by `$IFS`, so you have to clear that first.

```
while IFS= read line
do
  echo "file1:$line"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Escaping special characters:

```
printf -v prefix %q 'ab\cd%;,: /{][}-+*'; prefix=${prefix////\\/}; sed "s/^/$prefix/" file
```

Answer (score 1):

AWK equivalent of the sed answer:

```
awk '{gsub(/^/,"file1:")}1' file
```

Or just simply:

```
awk '{$0="file:1"$0}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl can handle this with no particular difficulty. I am testing them with the variable `$foo` which contains every weird character I can think of including the carriage return, space etc:

```
$ foo=$(echo -e "\r'{}[]- \`~^&%$=@\!#\"")
$ echo $foo | od -c
0000000  \r   '   {   }   [   ]   -       `   ~   ^   &   %   $   =   @
0000020   \   !   #   "  \n
0000025
$ export foo
```

So, to add these to the beginning and end of each line of file `bar.txt`:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; print "$ENV{foo}:$_:$ENV{foo}\n"' bar.txt
```

The `%ENV` hash contains the user's environment variables (which is why I export `$foo` above). The special variable `$_` contains the current line and `chomp` removes the trailing new line from it: